# Dual boot computer , vm on both partitions, can I run os from other partition without re installing it?

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

I have a dual boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu 16.04 computer. I have VM Ware on the windows partition with windows 10 as a guest on it. On Ubuntu I have Virtualbox with Parrot, Kali Linux, and Whonix as guest os's.  My question is, can I run the windows 10 (from my windows partition) on my Ubuntu Virtualbox without installing it on the Linux partition, thereby saving space on this one. Hope I have made this clear enough.  Thanks in anticipation.
Further to this, I would not mind removing VM Ware and replacing it with Virtualbox on the windows partition if it would simplify things. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have access to the Windows drive from Ubuntu what you need to do is

- Boot Windows 7.
- Get W10 running in VirtualBox ([Guide](https://www.maketecheasier.com/convert-virtual-machines-vmware-virtualbox/)).
- Reboot into Ubuntu.
- Make a backup of VirtualBox.xml (Both Linux- and Windows-file in case you mess up something).
- Copy the `MachineEntry` from VirtualBox.xml in Windows into VirtualBox.xml on Linux.
- Replace the `src=` of the VM to correspond to the path where the VM reside.
- Test

**VirtualBox.xml locations:**

```
Windows: C:\Users\<user>\.VirtualBox
Linux: /home/<user>/.config/VirtualBox/
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the info. I removed VMware Workstation and reinstalled Virtualbox, when i attempted to install thw Windows 10 virtual machine i got errors about other virtual software running (i dont remember the exact wording). I then switched to my Ubuntu and am currently in the process of installing Windows 10, but have selected a folder om my original Windows partition for the files. I have just checked and this works as I had hoped, that is it has installed on the Windows partition and left my much smaller linux partition size unchanged.  Once again, thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question and for your assistance.